# Deploying charms to Juju bootstrap node

Tags: juju, maas, cloud

Is it possible to deploy a charm to Juju bootstrap node (to a container) ?
I have not been able to add machine on which Juju controller resides, and see it in the list of available machines that can be targeted for charm deployment.
Tried, for example, with:

```
juju add-machine --constraints tags=juju
```

Error:

```
Machine  State    DNS  Inst id  Series  AZ  Message
0        pending       pending  xenial      failed to start machine 0 (failed to acquire node: No available machine matches constraints: [('zone', ['default']), ('agent_name', ['594543d5-4690-4f80-822a-60ea0446016a']), ('tags', ['juju'])] (resolved to "tags=juju zone=default")), retrying in 10s (5 more attempts)
```

The machine was successfully bootstrapped via (tag _is there)

```
 juju bootstrap --constraints tags=juju mymaas maas-controller --
 config=config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

The juju controller node is actually in a different **model**.  You can see it as long as you have the right permissions by doing:

```
dpb@helo:~[]$ juju models
Controller: localhost-localhost

Model        Cloud/Region         Status     Machines  Access  Last connection
controller*  localhost/localhost  available         1  admin   just now
default      localhost/localhost  available         0  admin   2018-02-26
```

Then, use `juju switch MODEL_NAME` to switch between them.  You have to be in the **controller** model to modify what used to be referred to as the bootstrap node (now called controller).